# Setting perms and giving roles to user

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, mute

I am trying to make a mute command for my bot and ran into these issues. I have been getting them for a very long time now.

```
const { Guild } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "Mutes a member",
    execute(message,args,Mention){
      if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") || message.author.username === "creepersaur"){
          let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
          const guild = message.guild
          
          let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
          if (!myRole) {
            
             newRole = message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                  name: 'Muted',
                  color: 'BLUE',
                  Permissions: '',
                },
                reason: `Make a muted role if it doesn't exist.`
             })
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.error); 

            //message.guild.roles.Muted.setPermissions({'SEND_MESSAGES': true})

            targetMember.roles.add(newRole).catch(console.error);
            message.channel.send(`${targetMember.username} has been muted!`);

          } else if (myRole) {
            targetMember.roles.add(myRole).catch(console.error);
            message.channel.send(`${targetMember.username} has been muted!`);
          }
      }
  }
};
```

It will see if there is a mute role in the server and if not, then it will create a mute role to give the user. Except the permissions don't work. And because of that, it is not giving the role itself to the user I want. :(
bump x1

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything bad in the role section but this code should have the permissions fixed.

```
const { Guild } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    description: "Mutes a member",
    execute(message,args,Mention){
      if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") || message.author.username === "creepersaur"){
          let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
          const guild = message.guild
          
          let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
          if (!myRole) {
            
             newRole = message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                  name: 'Muted',
                  color: 'BLUE',
                  Permissions: '',
                },
                reason: `Make a muted role if it doesn't exist.`
             })
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.error); 

            message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(ch => 
        {
        if(ch.type == "text") {
          ch.updateOverwrite(
          newRole, {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false
          }

            targetMember.roles.add(newRole).catch(console.error);
            message.channel.send(`${targetMember.username} has been muted!`);

          } else if (myRole) {
            targetMember.roles.add(myRole).catch(console.error);
            message.channel.send(`${targetMember.username} has been muted!`);
          }
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It still doesn't make the role though so I think the permissions section is the bugged part.

Comment: Well what I added was the part where people with the role can't talk soooo idk